# No sound after some minutes in Lenovo laptop with linux

Tags: ubuntu, audio, linux-mint, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo G460 laptop and this problem has appeared approximately a year ago, but I never had the time to look into it.

Right after I turn on my computer everything works fine. However, about 10 minutes my sound stops working.

I have installed Ubuntu mate and Linux Mint and the problem is the same with both. Naturally my first thought was a heating problem. However, I'm not so sure, because if I suspend my computer and turn it back on again (which takes approximately 7 seconds) the sound starts working again for another 3 minutes or so. I don't think those 7 seconds are enough for the hardware to cool down (if it was indeed a temperature problem).

Any ideas on what is the issue and how to fix it? I haven't found anything like it except [this](https://superuser.com/questions/982091/no-sound-after-5-minutes) similar question on a Windows computer, which wasn't helpful.

Also, I have tried a Fedora liveCD and the behavior was exactly the same as with Ubuntu and Mint.

Comment: Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, you should try with a Live CD of other LInux distribution or other operating system

Comment: @golimar Yes, I know, but I have tried several versions of Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Ubuntu Mate. Before I had this problem I actually had a successful ubuntu instalation. I will try a openSuse liveCD just in case.

Comment: @golimar I have tried a Fedora Live CD and the behavior is the same. I even tried suspending the laptop and then turning it on again and it worked for 40 more seconds and then stopped working again. I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: You will find several possible software solutions in [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203312/how-come-my-sound-wont-work-on-lenovo-thinkpad-x230), and a claim this is a hardware problem in [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/567255/thinkpad-speaker-turns-mute-linux-codec-issue).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks about those. I think the problem in the first thread was unrelated, since the guy had no sound at all (and indeed none of the fixes worked for me). However, I think the second link is about my problem exactly. Which is a hardware problem. If you post an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unlikely to be a software problem, since it happens in several operating systems.

This leaves hardware, where the problem must be with the motherboard itself.
Many references can be found over Google for such problems with Lenovo laptops.

For example, in the thread [Thinkpad speaker turns mute](https://superuser.com/questions/567255/thinkpad-speaker-turns-mute-linux-codec-issue), is said :

> It is a hardware problem, a design flaw. Supposedly Lenovo changed the
>   fan design with the T420.
>
> Lenovo is aware of the problem and they exchange the motherboard, no
>   questions asked. I am on my way to get the third motherboard. The
>   first had the flaw from the beginning. I tried pretty much everything
>   software related for the first 6 months. Then I talked to a Lenovo
>   dealer, and they said "Yes, we are aware of it." The second
>   motherboard worked for about 6 months.

Try to get in touch with Lenovo support, if they acknowledge the problem.
Otherwise you will have to continue using temporary workarounds.

Comment: I called Lenovo, though, and they don't wanna even consider it, since it's passed the warranty, so I'm going to open another question to see if I can fix it by myself.

Comment: To replace the motherboard (aka system board), you will need some expertise (or know someone). See this [video example](http://www.laptopinventory.com/LaptopInventory.php/Lenovo/G%20Series/G460/Motherboard) (not exactly for your model). On Amazon [this G460 board](http://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-IdeaPad-Motherboard-System--5751P/dp/B00Y2WV6J6/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1451330300&sr=8-2&keywords=G460+motherboard&refinements=p_n_condition-type%3A6461716011) is at $99.99. You could also envisage upgrading to a higher-model motherboard than the G460. But is buying a new laptop not better (not Lenovo)?

Comment: It probably would be a lot better to just buy a new model if I lived in the US or Europe, but were I live, laptops are way overpriced. So I'm trying to avoid at any cost to do that.

Comment: One can find motherboards for a lesser price on, for example, Alibaba.